# Problem in importing two certificates(ca.pem and key certificate) in java keystore for connecting to mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, ssl

I used the below command to add both the certificate to the keystore:

keytool -import -alias "mongodbconcat" -file "C:\Test\ca.cer" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass "changeit"

The ca certificate got imported without any issue but while adding the key certificate I started getting the certificate is not X.509 compatible, so i removed all the spaces in the certificate and it got imported.

We are using a springboot project with the below url details.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:password@hostserver:12345,hostserver:12345/dbname?authSource=admin&maxPoolSize=100&ssl=true

**Now while running the application I am getting the below exception:**

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:543)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    ...
2020-01-29 15:35:02,739 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='clusterId123', description='null'}-serverhost:12345] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server serverhost:12345
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:92)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm using Keystore Explorer application for this kind of stuff. Check it out for clear view.

Comment: Thanks Habil, I tried with the software you have suggested but still I am getting the same error.